# css responsive background image not showing

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am having trouble getting my image to display when there are no fixed height and width assigned.  I want my image to be flexy and responsive with my grid, so what I thought would work is to set height and width to 100% but no avail.

How can I get the image to show and be able to change size accordingly?

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="hero">
            <img id="image" src="steve1.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .hero {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0;

  }
```

Comment: I do not see a background image. Have you tried applying the width and height to `#image` instead of the container `.hero`?

Comment: you can also use media tag to build your website responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(steve1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
}
body{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the css:

```
.hero img {width:100%;}
```

You have to add the style to the img it self, not the container div.